# makefile file name parameter

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I remember doing this in my advanced C++ class, but it's been a couple years and I forgot.

I want to make a sort of simple re-usable makefile where I just type "make programName" and it compiles programName.cpp into programName.exe.

I've looked for this for a couple hours, but haven't found what I need. I know this will get marked as duplicate, but at least point me to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Make has a built-in variable called `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`, which contains all targets specified as command line parameters.

You can use it to generate recipes, like so:

```
# Stop if 0 or 2+ targets were specified.
$(if $(filter-out 1,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS))),$(error Expected one target))

name := $(MAKECMDGOALS)

$(name).exe: $(name).cpp
        g++ $^ -o $@
```

Adding a way to customize compiler executable and flags is left as an exercise to the reader. As well as conditionally removing `.exe` from the target name when building on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want your output to be suffixed with `.exe`?  That's a Windows convention that is not followed on POSIX systems like Linux.

If you don't want that you don't even need a makefile at all.  You can type `make programName` with no makefile and if you have a file `programName.c`, it will be built into an executable `programName` via make's built-in rules.

Comment: What about programName.cpp and C++ compiler?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu. In the file manager you can double click the exe files and it'll run them.

Comment: Re: `.cpp` files: yes, make knows how to build a `.cpp` file into an executable using the C++ compiler.  Re: file manager: yes... that's true... but that's true even if the file doesn't have a `.exe` extension.  POSIX systems don't use extensions for things like this, they use file permissions (whether the file has the executable bit set or not)